Unable to connect CloudFlare Domain with AWS EC2 running multiple docker images
I have purchased a domain example.com from CloudFlare. Set the certificate and the private key, in Cloudflare.
2 docker images are running in EC2 on different ports, Flask Hello Word on Port 3000 and Angular Hello World on Port 4000.
I want example.com:3000 to serve Flask and example.com:4000 to serve Angular.
Under CloudFlare domain DNS Records I have added



Type
Name
Content
Proxy Status
TTL




A
example.com
public ipv4 Address of EC2 Instance
DNS Only
Auto


A
www
public ipv4 Address of EC2 Instance
DNS Only
Auto



Flask Dockerfile
# Use Fedora as the base image
FROM fedora

# Update the package repository and upgrade all packages
RUN dnf upgrade -y

# Install pip and other necessary packages
RUN dnf install -y python3-pip gcc python3-devel

# Install Flask (this can be done using requirements.txt if specified)
# RUN pip3 install Flask

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the entire contents of the current directory to /app in the container
COPY . .

# Install Python dependencies from requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Expose the port that the Flask app will run on
EXPOSE 5000

# Set the environment variable for Flask
ENV FLASK_APP=run.py

# Run the Flask app
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

Angular Dockerfile
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:18 AS build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Build the Angular application for production
RUN npm run build --prod

# Use an official Nginx runtime as a parent image
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the built Angular app from the previous stage to the Nginx html directory
COPY --from=build /app/dist/sample-frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy the SSL certificates
COPY ssl/origin.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/origin.pem
COPY ssl/origin.key /etc/nginx/ssl/origin.key

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the custom Nginx configuration file to the Nginx configuration directory
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Expose port 443 to the outside world (HTTPS)
EXPOSE 443

# Start Nginx when the container launches
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Angular nginx.conf
# HTTP (port 80) to HTTPS (port 443) redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # SSL Certificate & Key
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/origin.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/origin.key;

    # Enable Strong SSL
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    # Serve Angular application
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Enable Gzip Compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain application/javascript text/css application/json;
    gzip_min_length 256;
}


and whats the question? what incorrect? do you have any logs with errors?
you need to double check your exposed ports, for example in Flask Dockerfile you did EXPOSE 5000 but in description you wrote that you want 3000 port for flask. for angular the same - you configured in nginx 80 and 443, but want to have 4000 port

The problem which I faced above and my approach to understanding and solving the problem were mismatched. Hence the above problem statement. I wanted to run 2 independent apps one Flask (Python) and one Angular (Node.js) on 1 EC2 Instance and be able to access them. I have found a solution below is the link to my GitHub repository with the approach explained in a detailed way. It works for my needs and there is room for improvement.
two-apps-aws-docker

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
